# Proving the differentiation rule for division

Tags: limits, derivatives

Prove $(\frac{u}{v})'=\frac{vu'-uv'}{v^2}$ where $u,v$ are differentiable functions of $x$ so i assumed $u=f(x),v=g(x)$ and then applied product rule for $u\cdot v^{-1}$ and got it but my book asks me to solve it with limits. Please help me with the proof. Just defined $dx,dy$ small change in x,y nothing beyond it. And dont think we need to use fisrt principle of derivative.

Comment: Do you know the limit definition of the derivative?

Comment: Yes $lim(h->0 \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=x'$

Comment: So define two functions, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ and see where you can get ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$$\frac{u(x)}{v(x)}-\frac{u(a)}{v(a)}=\frac{u(x)v(a)-u(a)v(x)}{v(x)v(a)}=\frac{(u(x)-u(a))v(a)-u(a)(v(x)-v(a))}{v(x)v(a)}.$$

---

Alternatively, with a more concise notation

$$\frac{u+du}{v+dv}-\frac uv=\frac{u\,dv-v\,du}{(v+dv)v}.$$

Comment: I deleted my answer. Brains malfunctioned there.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the atrocious formatting, but it's going to just be some finagling to get the definitions inside of the expression:

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{f}{g}(c+h)-\frac{f}{g}(c)}{h}
=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{f(c+h)}{g(c+h)}-\frac{f(c)}{g(c)}}{h}
=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(c+h)g(c)-f(c)g(c+h)}{hg(c)g(c+h)}$$
$$=\lim_{h \to 0}\left(\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}g(c)-f(c) \cdot \frac{g(c+h)-g(c)}{h}\right) \frac{1}{g(c)g(c+h)}$$

I hope you can see that we're almost done here.